# How to display math vertical multiplication?

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, math, latex

I am using [iOSMath Library](https://github.com/kostub/iosMath) for show math equations. So, I'm here to know about,

Can i show this type of equations using this library with latex ??, You can see the image below.

[Equation Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/koLdx.png)

Any Help would be appreciated.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Looks like no, but you can try contact developer at GitHub

Comment: Thanks @192kb, I already contacted developer at github

Comment: How are this library and LaTeX supposed to be combined together?